# The value of infinite product

Tags: infinite-product

At a first look I observed that every term of this product is less than 1 so the limit will also be less than 1 but clueless about how to find limit . 
$$P=\frac{7}{9}\cdot\frac{26}{28}\cdot\frac{63}{65}\cdots\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}\cdots.$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, multiplying by infinitely many terms less than 1 doesn't automatically mean the product is zero.  If you have $\prod_n a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = 0$, then I think it is true that $\prod_n a_n = 0$.  But here $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restate your question:
$$
\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}
$$
First we begin by expanding the terms:
$$
n^3-1 = (n-1)(n^2+n+1)
$$
$$
n^3+1 = (n+1)(n^2-n+1)
$$
By treating each term as a separate product,and shifting the index of the product, a telescope-like method can be used to simplify the terms into the desired answer.
\begin{align*}
\prod_{n\ge2}\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}
\\
= \frac{\left(\prod_{n \ge 0} n+1\right)\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2+n+1\right)}{\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n+1\right)\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2-n+1\right)}
\\
= \frac{2\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2+n+1\right)}{\left(\prod_{n \ge 1} (n+1)^2-(n+1)+1\right)}
\\
= \frac{2\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2+n+1\right)}{\left(\prod_{n \ge 1} n^2+(2-1)n+(1-1+1)\right)}
\\
= \frac{2\left(\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2+n+1\right)}{\left(\prod_{n \ge 1} n^2+n+1\right)}
\\
= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to consider finite products and then take the limit. Note that  $\prod_{n \ge 2} (n^2+n+1)$ and $\prod_{n \ge 1} (n^2+n+1)$ converge to $+\infty$ !!

Comment: True but that can be seen as a bit pedantic, i suppose it is the formal and most concrete way to ensure an answer so I will take the criticism. But to note that since the context is that the $n \ge 2$ is on the numerator and the $n \ge 1$ is on denominator, we can simply combine the two products into one
$$
\frac{\prod_{n \ge 2} n^2+n+1}{\prod_{n \ge 1} n^2+n+1} = \frac{1}{3}\prod_{n \ge 2} \frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n+1} = \frac{1}{3} \prod_{n \ge 2} \frac{1+\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
when the moment of the product is taken, limit as n approaches $\infty$ it is 1

Comment: So, in your opinion,
$$\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{\prod_{n\geq 1}(n+1)}{\prod_{n\geq 1}n}=\frac{\prod_{n\geq 2}n}{1\prod_{n\geq 2}n}=1?$$.

Comment: No, that is not the premise of the problem, the moment of each summation is over 1 and therefore the infinity product of something greater than 1 is of course going to diverge.

Comment: It does not matter, reverse may example. Do you think that
$$\prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{\prod_{n\geq 1}n}{\prod_{n\geq 1}(n+1)}=\frac{1\prod_{n\geq 2}n}{\prod_{n\geq 2}n}=1?$$

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying, or I misunderstood what you were saying. In the case of your example, the partial products are the same, neglecting the extra term in the denominator which gives the $\frac{1}{3}$ multiple, therefore dividing the remaining terms and taking the limit would yield 1 since the moments are the same.The asymptotic relationship between the numerator and denominator of the initial problem is extremely different from your counter example. evaluating this through partial product and then taking the limit can easily determine the difference as you stated.

Comment: I try to be more specific. At your first step, you split the infinite product in a ratio with 4 infinite products which are all divergent. This is dangerous!! In my example, I split a simpler infinite product in a similar way and I get the wrong answer. Try also this example which is more similar to the OP: $\prod_{n\geq 2}\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ what you get?

Comment: Yes i agree

This would be analogous to p-series I suppose, example:
$$
\prod_{n \ge 2} \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}
$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+n%5E1.00001%2F(n%5E1.00001%2B1),n%3D2+to+infinity

Like i said, more intuitive, less formal. Dangerous if you are callous with operation I completely agree.

Comment: Eric, You won. Have a nice day! Anyway it was an interesting talk.

Comment: hahaha all in good fun, you bring up good points and I will be sure to be sure to approach problems like these in the formal sense when the answer seems pathological, the logic used to reach my conclusion is dependent on information I left out of the problem. In fact, when I do things this way and get the wrong answer i find it pushed me to try to understand why I got it wrong in a certain instant. Guess im just unusual haha

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\ln\left(\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}\right)\\=\ln(n-1)-\ln(n+1)+\ln((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1)-\ln(n^2-n+1).$$
Hence, by  taking the logarithm of the partial product we obtain a telescoping sum,
$$\ln\left(\prod_{n=2}^N \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1} \right)=\sum_{n=2}^N \ln\left(\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}\right)\\=\ln(1)+\ln(2)-\ln(N)-\ln(N+1)+\ln(N^2+N+1)-\ln(3)\\
=\ln(2/3)+\ln\left(\frac{N^2+N+1}{N(N+1)}\right)\stackrel{N\to\infty}{\to} \ln(2/3).$$
Thus the infinite product yields $2/3$.

Comment: This is a nice approach, i'm somewhat confused on how you were able to see from the summation that the telescoping method would be employed, The answer is correct and your proof is elegant and formal, but to me it does not seem as easily obtainable from the information provided. Did you factor the numerator and denominator to see this or is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: Yes, factoring the numerator and the denominator is the key point. For more examples of telescoping series see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking. I took the approach of factoring first, then treating each term as its own product, and shifted each index accordingly. The approaches are virtually the same, but for me personally I find the shifting indexes more intuitive and less formal. To each his own i suppose.

Comment: That is fine. One more comment. Note that in my solution we treat only finite sum (or product) and then we take the limit. In the other solution the products $\prod_{n \ge 2} (n^2+n+1)$ and $\prod_{n \ge 1} (n^2+n+1)$ converge to $+\infty$ !!  So formally the ratio is undetermined.